# Dynamically set default selection in html with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using the following line of code to dynamically set the default selection of a selection box in html with jQuery

```
   var y=...a value from the DB;
   this.$(".status option[value=y]").attr("selected", "selected");
```

However, this only work if I replace it manually by saying option[value=3], I can't use a variable here.

I have already made sure what's from the DB is one of the option.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to use the jQuery [`val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method:

```
$(".status").val(y);
```

If you want to continue selecting the correct `option` and setting the `selected` attribute, then @redsquare's answer should do the trick, but note that you can also use `prop` instead of `attr` if you're using a later version of jQuery.

Comment: Thank you. Coding in php also confuses me up sometime

Answer (score 2):

In your scenario you need the following

```
$(".status option[value=" + y + "]").attr("selected", true);
```

However a better way is to do what James Allardice suggests in his answer by using `.val()`.

The best way would be to set this in your server side scripts and avoid any script whatsoever!